# Declarative mutations in Apollo Boost?

Tags: apollo

As Im using Apollo Boost I can write GraphQL queries declaratively like so: 
https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/zero-config-graphql-state-management-27b1f1b3c2c3

```
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';

const LOGGEDIN = gql`
    mutation($value: Boolean) {
        CurrentUserIsLoggedIn(value: $value) @client {
            value
        }
    }
`;

const Test = () => (
    <Query query={LOGGEDIN}>
        {({ loading, error, data }) => {
            if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
            if (error) return <div>Error :(</div>;
            console.log(data.CurrentUserIsLoggedIn.value);
            return <h2>Something</h2>;
        }}
    </Query>
);
```

Can I use a similar declarative approach to mutations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Evans, look at this, you'll find out not just the Mutation component  https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/tree/v2.1.0-beta.3/test/client, even inside of example project from article which you've mentioned, it's what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can see Declarative mutation in this repo..
https://github.com/apollographql/GitHunt-React